# Evaluating a time dependent variable out of NDsolve/in NDsolve without affecting the result

Tags: differential-equations

this is my first question here.
I am having trouble, I might be able to express what I want in Matlab but I suffer to do that in Mathematica.
So I have a direction cosine matrix that is solved in NDsolve. I have a vector,  say vec[0]={1,0,0}. I want to have these initial conditions and do a time marching to this vector (i.e. multiply it with my direction cosine matrix which is also time-dependent, and as mentioned solved in NDsolve). In the end, I want to create an animation of that vector.
I tried to put x' (first component of vector), y', and z' expression in the NDsolve where I get the components of direction cosine (please do not confuse it with built-in direction cosine it has nothing to do with my assignment); but it turned out that putting x', y', z' somehow managed to mess up my solution.
I am open to brand new approach to obtain this vector.
I add last part of my code below.

```
tmax = 10
m = 4
lx = 0.3
ly = 0.1
lz = 0.1
eqnplotorig = {Derivative[1][\[Theta]x][t] == 
   Sec[\[Theta]y[t]] (Cos[\[Theta]z[t]] \[Omega]x[t] - 
      Sin[\[Theta]z[t]] \[Omega]y[t]), 
  Derivative[1][\[Theta]y][t] == 
   Sin[\[Theta]z[t]] \[Omega]x[t] + Cos[\[Theta]z[t]] \[Omega]y[t], 
  Derivative[1][\[Theta]z][
    t] == -Cos[\[Theta]z[t]] Tan[\[Theta]y[t]] \[Omega]x[t] + 
    Sin[\[Theta]z[t]] Tan[\[Theta]y[t]] \[Omega]y[t] + \[Omega]z[t], 
  Derivative[1][\[Omega]x][
    t] == (36 lx^2 ly lz (ly^2 - lz^2) \[Omega]x[t]^2 - 
      3 lx \[Omega]x[
        t] ((9 ly^4 lz + 22 ly^2 lz^3 - 3 lz^5 - 
            lx^2 (11 ly^2 lz + 3 lz^3)) \[Omega]y[t] + 
         ly (3 ly^4 - 22 ly^2 lz^2 - 9 lz^4 + 
            lx^2 (3 ly^2 + 11 lz^2)) \[Omega]z[t]) - 
      4 (-3 ly (lx^2 - 2 ly^2) lz (lx^2 + lz^2) \[Omega]y[t]^2 + 
         2 (lx^2 + ly^2) (ly^2 - lz^2) (lx^2 + lz^2) \[Omega]y[
           t] \[Omega]z[t] + 
         3 ly (lx^2 + ly^2) lz (lx^2 - 2 lz^2) \[Omega]z[
           t]^2))/(5 lx^4 (ly^2 + lz^2) + 32 ly^2 lz^2 (ly^2 + lz^2) +
       lx^2 (5 ly^4 - 62 ly^2 lz^2 + 5 lz^4)), 
  Derivative[1][\[Omega]y][
    t] == (3 lx (5 lx^2 - 16 ly^2) lz (ly^2 + lz^2) \[Omega]x[
        t]^2 + \[Omega]x[
        t] (3 ly lz (lx^2 (-23 ly^2 + lz^2) + 
            12 (ly^2 + lz^2)^2) \[Omega]y[
           t] + (lx^2 + ly^2) (5 lx^2 + 12 ly^2 - 20 lz^2) (ly^2 + 
            lz^2) \[Omega]z[t]) + 
      3 lx (3 ly^2 lz (-4 lx^2 + 3 ly^2 + 7 lz^2) \[Omega]y[t]^2 + 
         ly (3 ly^4 + 20 ly^2 lz^2 + 9 lz^4 + 
            lx^2 (3 ly^2 - 13 lz^2)) \[Omega]y[t] \[Omega]z[
           t] + (lx^2 + ly^2) lz (7 ly^2 - 5 lz^2) \[Omega]z[
           t]^2))/(5 lx^4 (ly^2 + lz^2) + 32 ly^2 lz^2 (ly^2 + lz^2) +
       lx^2 (5 ly^4 - 62 ly^2 lz^2 + 5 lz^4)), 
  Derivative[1][\[Omega]z][
    t] == (-3 lx ly (5 lx^2 - 16 lz^2) (ly^2 + lz^2) \[Omega]x[
        t]^2 - \[Omega]x[
        t] ((lx^2 + lz^2) (ly^2 + lz^2) (5 lx^2 - 20 ly^2 + 
            12 lz^2) \[Omega]y[t] + 
         3 ly lz (lx^2 (ly^2 - 23 lz^2) + 
            12 (ly^2 + lz^2)^2) \[Omega]z[t]) + 
      3 lx ((lx^2 + lz^2) (5 ly^3 - 7 ly lz^2) \[Omega]y[t]^2 - 
         lz (9 ly^4 + 20 ly^2 lz^2 + 3 lz^4 + 
            lx^2 (-13 ly^2 + 3 lz^2)) \[Omega]y[t] \[Omega]z[t] - 
         3 ly lz^2 (-4 lx^2 + 7 ly^2 + 3 lz^2) \[Omega]z[
           t]^2))/(5 lx^4 (ly^2 + lz^2) + 32 ly^2 lz^2 (ly^2 + lz^2) +
       lx^2 (5 ly^4 - 62 ly^2 lz^2 + 5 lz^4)), \[Theta]x[0] == 
   0, \[Theta]y[0] == 0, \[Theta]z[0] == 0, \[Omega]x[0] == 
   2 \[Pi]/180, \[Omega]y[0] == 2 \[Pi]/180, \[Omega]z[0] == 
   2 \[Pi]/180}
solplot3Dorig = 
 Flatten@NDSolve[
   eqnplotorig, {\[Theta]x, \[Theta]y, \[Theta]z, \[Omega]x, \
\[Omega]y, \[Omega]z}, {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[Evaluate[{\[Theta]x[t], \[Theta]y[t], \[Theta]z[t]} /. 
   solplot3Dorig], {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{\[Theta]x[t], \[Theta]y[t], \[Theta]z[t]}, {0.85, 0.55}]]
Plot[Evaluate[{\[Omega]x[t], \[Omega]y[t], \[Omega]z[t]} /. 
   solplot3Dorig], {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{\[Omega]x[t], \[Omega]y[t], \[Omega]z[t]}, {0.85, 0.55}]]
```

Here I solve \theta values that will be used in my direction cosine matrix. Which is defined as :

```
Dirmat = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[\[Theta]x[t]], -Sin[\[Theta]x[t]]}, {0, 
    Sin[\[Theta]x[t]], Cos[\[Theta]x[t]]}} . {{Cos[\[Theta]y[t]], 0, 
    Sin[\[Theta]y[t]]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[\[Theta]y[t]], 0, 
    Cos[\[Theta]y[t]]}} . {{Cos[\[Theta]z[t]], -Sin[\[Theta]z[t]], 
    0}, {Sin[\[Theta]z[t]], Cos[\[Theta]z[t]], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

So what I need is a "vec" vector variable time march that has some initial values like {1,0,0} (or whatever) and time march it so that I can animate it using "frames" or something like that.

Sorry, it was a long question.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What actually do you  try to visualize?

Comment: I am trying to visualize the vector over time. It is supposed to be on the cubesat that  I model. Cubesat has an initial angular velocity so it will do a tumbling motion. The visualization part is not really my primary concern right now I need to time march "vec" vector over time. I is supposed to be done with a "for" loop in Matlab but I don't know how to do it in Mathematica. I tried piecewise but program crashed.

Comment: Is my interpretation correct: the time dependend matrix `Dirmat[t_] = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 
     Cos[\[Theta]x[t]], -Sin[\[Theta]x[t]]}, {0, Sin[\[Theta]x[t]], 
     Cos[\[Theta]x[t]]}}.{{Cos[\[Theta]y[t]], 0, 
     Sin[\[Theta]y[t]]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[\[Theta]y[t]], 0, 
     Cos[\[Theta]y[t]]}} /. solplot3Dorig` gives the drivative of `vec` :` vec'[t]= Dirmat[t] .vec[t]

Comment: I can express the derivative mathematically, which I believe what creates problem to me:
$$vec'[t]=(Dirmat[t] .vec[t]-vec[t])/(\delta t)$$
As my current vector is vec and next time step vector is Dirmat[t] .vec[t].

Comment: I am sorry I need to update it to be more clear. Below I derived what I have written previously.
$$ vec(t+\delta t)=Dirmat . vec(t) \\

vec(t+\delta t)-vec(t)=Dirmat . vec(t)- vec(t) \\
[vec(t+\delta t)-vec(t)]/ \delta t =(Dirmat-1) . vec(t) / \delta t\\

vec’(t)=(Dirmat-1) . vec (t)/ \delta t $$
Above 1 is identity matrix.

Comment: You can even go further above and write,
$$
vec'(t)=(Dirmat-I).vec(t)/\delta t
vec'(t)/vec(t)=(Dirmat-I)/\delta t
$$
Notice $$vec'(t)/vec(t)$$ is derivative of $$ln vec(t)$$ with respect to time,
$$
d(ln vec(t))/dt=(Dirmat-I)/\delta t
$$
This does not solve $$\delta t$$ problem though.